# alt+selection wont work as expected

Tags: selection-tools

I want to select the horizontal rings not the cross sections, but <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> will randomly choose between either as seen below it selected the horizontal correctly but for the one cell above it selected a vertical strip.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Blender's *Loop Select* tool usually doesn't select "random" loops. To select a horizontal loop you have to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> click on the vertical edge between two horizontal adjacent faces (yellow, see image below). To select a vertical loop you have to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> click on the horizontal edge between two vertical adjacent faces (red). If you click more or less the center of a face because you were not aware of this functionality, Blender will choose the direction depending on which edge your cursor will be closest to.

[image: loop select]

Answer (score 10):

You mean that sometimes it selects from top to bottom and sometime from left to right? Well, that is perfectly fine as it should be but you are doing it wrong, you don't have to select randomly in your face and expect it to select what you want.

You need to put your cursor closer to what you want to select, for example:
If you place your mouse on top or bottom edge, it will select from top to bottom:
[image]

If you will place your mouse on left or right edge, it will select from left to right:
[image]

This is whole functionality for loops selection

Comment: You were quicker... I'm too slow, I have to give up on making "beautiful" images as explanation. :D